# How to reorder grouped items with ion-reorder

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I'm trying to use [ion-reorder](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/reorder) to reorder some items in a page. These item are organized in groups, so a group has several items. I want to organize these items inside the group, but more importantly I want to be able to change the item from a group to another.

I'm facing 2 problems currently:

- I can't update the array, consequently the item orders are not show correctly when changed.
- I can't move a item outside it's group, consequently I can't move to another group.

---

*html*

```html
<ion-content>   
    <ion-list *ngFor='let group of groupArray'>
        <ion-reorder-group (ionItemReorder)="doReorder($event)" disabled="false">
            <ion-list-header>{{group.name}}</ion-list-header>           
            <ion-item *ngFor='let item of group.items'>
                <ion-reorder slot="start"></ion-reorder>
                <ion-label>
                    {{item.name}}
                </ion-label>
            </ion-item>
        </ion-reorder-group>
    </ion-list>     
</ion-content>
```

*typescript*

```js
interface Item {
    id: number,
    name: string
}
interface Group {
    name: string,
    items: Item[]
}
interface GroupArray extends Array<Group>{}

...

private groupArray: GroupArray = [
    {
        name: 'FirstGroup',
        items: [
            {
                id: 1,
                name: 'FirstItem'
            },{
                id: 2,
                name: 'SecondItem'
            },{
                id: 3,
                name: 'ThirdItem'
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        name: 'SecondGroup',
        items: [
            {
                id: 4,
                name: 'FourthItem'
            },{
                id: 5,
                name: 'FifthItem'
            },{
                id: 6,
                name: 'SixthItem'
            }
        ]
    }       
];

/** Reorder */
doReorder(ev: CustomEvent<ItemReorderEventDetail>) {
    this.groupArray = ev.detail.complete(this.groupArray);
}
```

---

I tried to move the `<ion-reorder-group>` to several positions, but this is the only one I managed to move the correct items. If I move up, above `<ion-list>`, the whole list becomes draggable and I can't move the item.

I understand that this is happening because the `<ion-reorder-group>` is created 2 times, but I can't think in a way to create only one time and maintain the same aspect, which is exactly like the documentation page that I linked. The difference is that in there they load the items individually, and the groups are just another item that can be drag around.

The other problem I believe is related to how `complete()` works. Although it expects `any[]` as a parameter, I don't think it was made to support a complex structure, just a simple array.

How can I solve these two problems?

---

*I'm using Ionic 5 with Angular 10*

[**StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-5-angular-10-start-template-dwsdjp?devtoolsheight=33&file=src/app/tab1/tab1.page.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the reording issue, you have two things

- You are sending the wrong items to the `complete` function, it should be the rendered items (`groupArray[index].items`), not the root object itself (`groupArray`).
- The `ion-list-header` should be above the `ion-reorder-group`, so Ionic won't treat it as a child of the `ion-reorder-group` and mess up the reording logic for the array.

Even though the example in the [attached link for the ion-reorder](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/reorder) is using one big `ion-reorder-group` and the `ion-list-header` to add some list headers, but this won't work if you need to update the array using the `complete`.

You can do something like this to make it work:

```
doReorder(ev: CustomEvent<ItemReorderEventDetail>, groupId: number) {
  let groupToChangeIndex = this.groupArray.findIndex(
    group => group.id === groupId
  );
  this.groupArray[groupToChangeIndex].items = ev.detail.complete(
    this.groupArray[groupToChangeIndex].items
  );
}
```

HTML:

```
<ion-content>
  <ion-list *ngFor='let group of groupArray'>
    <ion-list-header>{{group.name}}</ion-list-header>
    <ion-reorder-group (ionItemReorder)="doReorder($event, group.id)" disabled="false">
      <ion-item *ngFor='let item of group.items'>
        <ion-reorder slot="start"></ion-reorder>
        <ion-label>
          {{item.name}}
        </ion-label>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-reorder-group>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

At the same time, you can't move an ion-item from one group to another.
What I can think of for handling this issue is to have one big `ion-reorder-group` with the `ion-list-header`, and do the reording manually. Accessing the `target` property from the event that was sent to the `doReorder` function, then you can access the children, filter only the `ion-item` then reflect the sorting to the array (even though it is a very ugly workaround).

---

### Update

I actually thought of a better solution. You can create a new array that contains all the items flattened. Then when you want to submit you changes, there will be a function that will create the new order for you. You can check the following Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-5-angular-10-start-template-zasssd?file=src/app/tab1/tab1.page.ts

```
constructor() {
  this.allItemsFlattened = this.groupArray.flatMap((group, index) => [
    { isHeader: true, index: index, name: group.name },
    ...group.items
  ]);
}

/** Reorder objects in array */
doReorder(ev: CustomEvent<ItemReorderEventDetail>) {
  this.allItemsFlattened = ev.detail.complete(this.allItemsFlattened);
}

getRightOrder() {
  const rightOrder = this.allItemsFlattened.reduce((accumlator, item) => {
    if (item.isHeader) {
      const { id, name, ...rest } = this.groupArray[item.index];
      accumlator.push({ id, name, items: [] });
    } else {
      accumlator[accumlator.length - 1].items.push(item);
    }
    return accumlator;
  }, []);
  console.log(rightOrder);
}
```

Comment: I tried to use your method, but the target property returns everything that is inside of `<ion-reorder-group>` in the order before being rearranged, so I can't filter an element from it because I can't know what element is, considering that this list is big and dynamic. I tried to search every element in the event, but none return me a reference to the moved object.

Comment: Can  you add a StackBlitz for this?

Comment: Of course! I tried to comment the important things and added what I'm trying to do now. https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-5-angular-10-start-template-cz6vh4?file=src/app/tab1/tab1.page.ts .

Comment: This is a way better approach than the way I was trying to do. I even thought of doing something like this, but didn't even have a clue on how to do. It was also a great oportunity to learn more about `flatMap()` and `reduce()`. I believe with this both question are now answered. Thank you very much for all your help.

Comment: I'm happy to hear that! Glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

I personally used this approach.

```
ngOnint(){
this.item.items = result[1]; 

if (this.item?.itemSortOrder != null) {
// converting string to array
let itemSortOrder= this.item.itemSortOrder.split(","); 

this.newIndexArray = itemSortOrder
                           .map((i) => this.item.items.find((j) => j.id === i))
                           .filter(e => e !== undefined && e !== null); 
    }}
    
doReorder(ev: CustomEvent<ItemReorderEventDetail>) {
    console.log('Dragged from index', ev.detail.from, 'to', ev.detail.to);
    this.newIndexArray = ev.detail.complete(this.newIndexArray);
  }

saveReorder() {
    let newOrderPosition: string[] = [];
    this.newIndexArray.forEach((x) => {
      newOrderPosition.push(x.id); //adding sorted new item id's to an array
    })

    //array to string
    this.item.itemSortOrder = newOrderPosition.toString();

   //Passing the newArray order of items to the server
    this.newService.updateCatalog(this.item)
      .subscribe((result) => {
        console.log(result);
      });
  }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).